# Wall functions and separation in turbine blade simulation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbulence, cfd

I am simulating a turbine and I have some question about standard wall function in FLUENT.

Standard wall function requires $y^+$ value between 30 to 60 on the blade. but the following quote states:

> When using wall function models, the $y^+$ value should ideally be above
>   15 to avoid erroneous modelling in the buffer layer and the laminar
>   sub-layer [[Source]](http://www.computationalfluiddynamics.com.au/turbulence-part-3-selection-of-wall-functions-and-y-to-best-capture-the-turbulent-boundary-layer/#comment-7471)

Why $y^+$ value should ideally be above 15 by using wall functions?
Can massive separation be modeled with $y^+$ value between 30 to 60 on the blade? because it is mentioned according to FLUENT help:

> Traditionally, there are two approaches to modeling the near-wall
>   region. In one approach, the viscosity-affected inner region (viscous
>   sublayer and buffer layer) is not resolved. Instead, semi-empirical
>   formulas called "wall functions'' are used to bridge the
>   viscosity-affected region between the wall and the fully-turbulent
>   region. The use of wall functions obviates the need to modify the
>   turbulence models to account for the presence of the wall.

In other words, I think that there is a velocity profile in viscosity-affected inner region as a wall function that it can almost model boundary layer and massive separation. For example, wall functions with 30

I studied [this article](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Fluent6/html/ug/node512.htm) but I don't understand the following sentences:

> The logarithmic law for mean velocity is known to be valid for . In
>   FLUENT, the log-law is employed when . It should be noted that, in
>   FLUENT, the laws-of-the-wall for mean velocity and temperature are
>   based on the wall unit, $y^*$ , rather than $y^+$. These quantities are
>   approximately equal in equilibrium turbulent boundary layers.

What is difference between $y^*$ and $y^+$? What is the exact meaning of *"equilibrium turbulent boundary layers"*?

Generally, my question is that when wall function approach is used, viscosity-affected inner region (viscous sublayer and buffer layer) is computed by using semi-empirical formulas with good accuracy. Is this statement correct?

Comment: It has been too long since I have used fluent to be of any help, but here is a good place to re-post this question. http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/fluent/

Comment: This might be useful: [Why does the standard $k-\epsilon$ model use zero equation models?](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5528/why-does-the-standard-k-epsilon-model-use-zero-equation-models?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Wall function solves buffer layer and outer layer, but not viscous sublayer. see [law of the wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_wall) explanation from wiki.

For flow separation modelling, sub-viscous Boudnary layer (yplus<5) need to be resolved, thus yplus < 2, use SST k-omega RANS, or more advanced models.

y* is almost identical to Y+, detail see  "wall function and near wall treatement" in theory guide of fluent.